# absolute positioned element does not fill container width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a red line which I want to stretch horizontally within a div which is scrolled:

```css
 
.p
{
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto; /* so that scrollbar appears */
    position: relative; /* this is required by the absolute positioning of the line */
}

.box
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 3000px; /* such that horizontal scrollbar appears */
}

.line{
    border-top: 1px dashed red; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    top: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<div class='p'>
    <div class='box'></div>
    <div class='line'></div>
</div>
```

The problem is the line doesn't stretch once you scroll.

Why isn't working and how to fix this?

A solution which doesn't use JavaScript is preferable if possible, obviously.

**UPDATED:**
Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mwznLh1p/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a first look I would add .line{width: 3000px} (equals the margin-left) and remove {right:0}. I also added the line to be yellow and see that is not overlapping with the red box

```css
 
.p
{
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto; /* so that scrollbar appears */
    position: relative; /* this is required by the absolute positioning of the line */
}

.box
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 3000px; /* such that horizontal scrollbar appears */
}

.line{
    border-top: 1px dashed yellow; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 3000px;
    top: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<div class='p'>
    <div class='box'></div>
    <div class='line'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, setting width I guess is one way. but why isn't it working with my code?

Comment: Because the rule right:0 tells the div to stop at the viewport right margin.

Comment: do you have a reference where I can read about viewport and how it works in respect to the scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you.

If not let me know, there can be a better solution for it.

```
 .p {
            background-color: blue;
            overflow: auto;
            /* so that scrollbar appears */
            position: relative;
            /* this is required by the absolute positioning of the line */
        }

        .box {
            background-color: red;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            margin-left: 3000px;
            /* such that horizontal scrollbar appears */
        }

        .line {
            border-top: 1px dashed red;
            overflow: auto;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            top: 50px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with position:fixed;

```
 .line {
    border-top: 1px dashed red;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: this positions the line relatively to the viewport, not the <p> element

Answer (score 0):

You can give `width` to the line..

```
.line{
    border-top: 1px dashed red; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 1000px;
    top: 50px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change these two lines:

```
line{
    left: -9999px; 
    right: -9999px;
}
```

Comment: crazy hacky, but interesting :) but why isn't it working with right:0 ? I wish I could up-vote your answer

Comment: left and right just determine where the line starts and ends - they're not concerned with how wide it needs to be. The renderer will work that out. This just says start the line 10k pixels to the left and keep going until you hit 10k pixels to the right of the container. You just have to hope your container won't get wide enough to notice (and if it ever does you have probably have bigger problems...).